# Overriding the "Select Template" button in Email Author

Tags: apex, email-template, button-overrides

Is there a way to over-ride the "Select Template" button in the Salesforce standard email author page with a custom visualforce page ?

[image: Select Template button on the Email Author]

Comment: I do not think this possible. The email editor is not a configurable page. What is your use case?

Comment: There are a lot of email templates in our org and the way it is organized under folders takes a lot of time for a user to choose the correct template. We want to sort the email templates in a more efficient way with more sub folders.